# Maximum of $|(\sin (z)/z)-\cos (\alpha z)|$ on the disk $|z| \leq\pi/4$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am  trying to find the following maximum, whose existence is justified by the compactness of the close ball $\Delta$  of $\mathbb C$  and continuity of the function

$$f(z)=\frac{\sin (z)}{z}-\cos (\alpha  z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n z^{2n}\left(\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}-\frac{\alpha^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)$$

from $\mathbb C$   to  $\mathbb C$ (where $\alpha\in \mathbb R$, $|\alpha|\leq 1$)

$$\max_{z \in {\mathbb C},|z| \leq \frac{\pi}{4}} \left|f(z)\right|$$

My approach.
Before applying Maximum Modulus Principle, we rewrite the function in this way:

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\alpha^{2n}\right)$$

Then

$$
\max_{z \in {\mathbb C},|z| \leq r} \left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\alpha^{2n}\right)\right|
= \max_{z \in {\mathbb C},|z| = r} \left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\alpha^{2n}\right)\right|
= \max_{\theta\in \mathbb R} \left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{r^{2n}e^{2n\theta i}}{(2n)!}\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\alpha^{2n}\right)\right|$$.
So, for every $\theta\in \Bbb{R}$  we have
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{r^{2n}e^{2n\theta i}}{(2n)!}\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\alpha^{2n}\right)\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)!} r^{2n} \left|\frac{1}{2n+1}-\alpha^{2n}\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)!} r^{2n}=\cosh(r)-1
$$
with eqaulity if $\theta=0$. My result is based on the simplification:
$$\left|\frac{1}{2n+1}-\alpha^{2n}\right|\leq 1$$
This is my approach. Any suggestions to improve the final estimate?

Comment: Why not use the closed form of your $f(z)$ which equals to $\frac{\sin z}{z} - \cos(\alpha z)$.

Comment: what is the region in which function is defined?

Comment: Because I thought it was easier to work with the series. However, I will modify the post so that they are visible all my steps.

Comment: I'm interested in $z\leq \pi/4$

Comment: seems okay to me ;)

Comment: Do you think there are better estimates of $\left|\frac{1}{2n+1}-\alpha^{2n}\right|\leq 1$?